# Origine e diffusione dell'espressione "che levati!"

Tags: idioms, phrase-origin

Leggendo il seguente post su Twitter:

> Ho letto un bellissimo articolo sulle proprietà benefiche dei
>   mirtilli.
>  E m'è venuta 'na voglia di pane e mortadella ***che levati***

ho soffermato l'attenzione sull'espressione "***che levati***", che come riportato in [questo blog](https://www.laputa.it/lexicon/tag/che-levati/) significa:

> eccezionale, esagerato, da lasciare sbalorditi, da spavento ecc…
>   espressione idiomatica in uso aggettivale enfatico (sia positivo che
>   negativo) con il significato di  “…(tanto) che non ha nemmeno senso
>   parlarne”.

Lo stesso blog afferma che l'espressione è usata già almeno dagli anni '60.

> Diffusasi su internet soprattutto dalla seconda metà degli anni 2000,
>   viene spesso ulteriormente enfatizzata con l’avverbio proprio: «Di un
>   barboso che lèvati, proprio…» (Doc. Manhattan, 2012). L’espressione è
>   usata già almeno dagli anni ’60,

Qualcuno di voi ha fonti più attendibili sull'origine e la diffusione di questa espressione?

Comment: Non posso aiutare riguardo all'origine, ma riguardo alla diffusione posso dire che a me (lombardo) suona dialettale romanesca, anche se ovviamente se ne intuisce il senso. Non penso sia un'espressione usata ovunque.

Comment: L'espressione appare nel romanzo *Un amore* di Dino Buzzati, scritto nel 1959: «Non è una pecorella la Laide è una tipa stagna ha un orgoglio che levati».